# PixiJS - how to change the cursor on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js, mouse-cursor

following the little advice I could find, I have:

```
var btn = new PIXI.Sprite.fromFrame( 'btn_img.png' );
btn.interactive = true;
btn.buttonMode = true;
btn.defaultCursor = 'pointer';
```

... with no change in the cursor on mouseover. If I try:

```
btn.mouseover = function() { console.log("foo"); };
```

... I see that the event is indeed firing.

Any help? Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

solved it. the DOM elements ontop of the canvas were masking mouse events. adding `pointer-events: none` to those elements fixed things.